# Building from PyCharm using a Docker interpreter

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I'm trying to build a Python project using a Docker interpreter directly from PyCharm. I can run scripts fine if I use the "Run" command directly; it's specifically that the build tool in PyCharm looks for setup.py at its location on my local machine. For example, if I hit the play button on a script called test.py in the top-level directory of the project, the actual command PyCharm executes is "python -u /opt/project/test.py," which is the correct location of the file within the Docker container. However, when I try to use "Tools -> Run setup.py Task" to actually build the project, the command it executes is "python -u /Users/myname/myproject/setup.py build_ext," (i.e. the location of setup.py on my local,) and I get the error

```
python: can't open file '/Users/myname/myproject/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to specify where PyCharm should look for the build file, or to provide the build tool with the mapping from my local machine to the volume in the Docker container? Is this actually a bug? I can work around this by using subprocess.call to run setup.py with the appropriate arguments, but it would be nice to be able to use PyCharm directly.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a directory mapping?

Comment: I just tried by adding the mapping:
`<Project root>/setup.py→/opt/project/setup.py`
This should be the correct mapping - I checked by hitting the play button on setup.py, which runs but gives me an error that no command was supplied, as expected. Curiously, when I try "Run setup.py Task," it now looks in the correct place (/opt/project/setup.py,) but still tells me the file doesn't exist, despite having just run `python -u /opt/project/setup.py` without issue using the play button.

Comment: You can try to set the mapping more generally to: `<Project root>→/opt/project` instead. Make sure to set this mapping at the different places where PyCharm allows you to specify mappings (once it works you can remove those that are redundant).

Comment: If you are using Docker for Windows (beta), make sure to have shared your C drive in the settings (if your project root is in this drive). With other VM versions of Docker, make sure that your project root is within a host folder already shared with the VM (I struggled for hours with the same `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` as you until I found out that my C drive wasn't shared... so mounting a host folder wasn't really mounting any file even if no error was reported).